# Adjust width/height of Webview on Window resize

Tags: macos, cocoa

Am using a webview to load initial screen for a Mac app. I have implemented the NSWindow delegates to get the new width & height of window using `windowWillResize`. This would return the window size. Now how can I set the webview width & height when window is being resized ?

I tried using `[webView setFrameSize:frameSize];` in the `windowWillResize` method, but it didnt work.

Comment: could you finally solve this? I'm getting the same issue..

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol I wasnt setting constraints properly. If you add all needed constraints subviews will resize automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add the frame size of the WebView. You should resize the documentView while load.

NSView *clipView = [[[[_mainWebView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] superview];

[clipView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(0.5, 0.5)];